# Leaderboard with rank - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this

```
+-----+-------+
| pid | score | 
+-----+-------+      
|   1 |    120|          
|   2 |    130|    
|   3 |    100|    
|   1 |    120|        
|   2 |    130|    
|   3 |    100|      
+-----+-------+
```

I am trying to get get my users ranking. Currently I am using this query,

```
SELECT pid
     , SUM(score) AS total_score
  FROM score 
 GROUP 
    BY pid 
 ORDER 
    BY total_score DESC
```

I am getting a sorted list by score with this query but not getting their position. I want something like this

```
+-----+-------+------+
| pid | score | rank |
+-----+-------+------+       
|   2 |    260|    1 |       
|   1 |    240|    2 |
|   3 |    200|    3 |       
+-----+-------+------+
```

And can I get this position for a specific user? Like

```
+-----+-------+------+
| pid | score | rank |
+-----+-------+------+       
|   1 |    240|    2 |        
+-----+-------+------+
```

I am using MySQL 5.7.21. Can you please help?

Comment: What MySQL version are you use?

Comment: You can use `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) WHERE pid = 2`

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7.21 :( @ArtemIlchenko

Comment: Sorry. That was a mistake @Strawberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the chance to be in Mysql 8.0.2 or more you have the function rank.

Else You can use a variable to set the rank:

```
SELECT pid,
       total_score,
       @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM
    (SELECT pid,
            sum(score) AS total_score
     FROM score
     GROUP BY pid
     ORDER BY total_score DESC) datas, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
```

You can filter after to get only the result for the pid you want

Comment: I am using AWS's MySQL 5.7.21 :(

Comment: @SamiulHSohan take my request in a subselect and make ‘where Id = YourId’ and that will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use LIMIT like:

```
SELECT pid, SUM(score) AS total_score 
FROM score 
GROUP BY pid 
ORDER BY total_score DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I am trying to get rank for a specific user.